# How to cover old Red Dot outdoor outlet for constant use?

Tags: electrical, receptacle, safety, outdoor, weather-resistant

Here's the current outlet.
I need to leave a cable connected constantly.
Is there a snap-on cover for this type of thing?
(Can I gaff tape a quart baggie over it?)

tia...

[image: outlet]

[image: outlet]

[image: outlet]

[image: outlet open]

[image: outlet open]

Comment: NEC 110.3 must follow labeling and instructions, as long as the quart baggie has UL-approved instructions that say how to protect an in-use outlet, nothing the AHJ can say :)

Comment: Home desperate has the mx6200 you can use your existing box and switch /receptacle. If you decide to upgrade from a duplex to a WR GFCI receptacle. The correct pattern for that combination will be in the box.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think mark f has already answered your question well.  I just wanted to add some photos from a similar project I did last year in case these are helpful to you.

I installed a [weatherproof cover](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0039ZCUMY) and [box](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0044FX108) to replace the old ones that supplied my above-ground pool.  Fair warning: don't do this at your own pool because my installation was deficient in several ways; but I bought the house with some problems already existing, and I just needed to make a repair and add GFCI for my own comfort; my city didn't care.

Anyway, first picture is what the box looked like with a couple duplex receptacles in it.  Hopefully, you won't need a new box; but if you do, they come with plenty of plugs and conduit bushings.
[image: first picture]

I prepared the wiring in my garage:
[image: preparing wiring]

Then I have the parts that came with the cover; that's the cover itself plus a gasket that makes it watertight.
[image: weatherproof cover parts]

Here's what the box looks like with the gasket fitted:
[image: gasket installed]

And now with the cover attached using four mounting screws:
[image: cover attached]

What it looks like when closed:
[image]

Finished, with a cord plugged in:
[image: finished and cord plugged in]

I hope this helps!

Comment: Love the label on the switch.

Comment: If it needs a label, the design is poor or complex. [Don Norman The Design of Everyday Things]

Answer (score 11):

I would suggest an update to a extra duty double gang cover.
Extra duty or “in use” covers are made to be used while something is plugged in.
Taymac mx6200 is a cover that has 55 configurations made by Hubbell this will replace your existing cover and it has switch plates and receptacle plates that snap in so your configuration is what you need.

This is a cast aluminum they cost a couple of extra dollars compared to a plastic one but the difference between plastic and aluminum is, these are tough and last!

I rarely see plastic ones that the cover is not  broken or being held in place with tape.
This is what I use and recommend I have no interest of connection to them.

Comment: Thank you, so this would work with the existing box? I just switch out the front plate? Box is 4 3/4" square, 2.5" deep.

Comment: Yes that is a standard 2 gang bell box and it would fit like a glove. I would advise to use a metal one as the plastic ones always get broken in my experience bell boxes or weatherproof come in 1 gang , 2 gang and 3 gang,,, you have s standard 2 gang. The boxes that have knockouts like the 4x4 called a 4-0 and 4-3/4 are not weatherproof.

Answer (score 6):

Replace the existing cover (and switch plate) with a new two gang outdoor cover such as one like this:
[image]

The new cover seals against the existing outdoor rated handy box via a weather seal.

You will likely need to put a new cover plate over the switch as well.  And be sure the Outlet or entire Circuit is  GFCI protected since its outside.

Comment: Ed's right about the plastic,  first time something whacks it, it breaks the hinge off.  But this ones $12 and the better metal ones are >20... and you can see through these plastic ones  :)

Comment: Thank you, so this would work with the existing box? I just switch out the front plate? Box is 4 3/4" square, 2.5" deep.

Comment: go to your favorite hardware store, and find one with the proper box size they come in 4x4 and 4.25x4.25 and probably 4.75x4.75 also.  you might want to pull the existing cover (with breaker off) and check the screw pattern for the cover too. And look for Ed's aluminum cover, you will likely be glad you did in a few years when the plastic one failed...

Comment: thank you - added a couple of pics of the box open, is that showing what you meant by checking the screw pattern?

Comment: given the age,  you might replace the switch at this time too  (the wrapped in tape concerns me)... and convert the sockets to a GFCI outlet!

Comment: I just checked the big orange store $15.32 you can’t see through them but your receptacle and switch will stay dry worth the 3-4$ in my opinion and they can be locked with a padlock.